# Moving div with slide transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I have a page with Video background and a div with some text on it, I want to put a button in center of page so that when users click on it, the current div (text) slide up with css transition and another div show up with same transition.

I want to move just divs with fixed background.

What is the best way to make this effect happens?

Comment: Looks like your new. You should post your code attempt and if possible a jsfiddle.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Show us what you have tried so far and where you are stuck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var oT = $('#old'),
  nT = $('#new').css({
    top: '+=50',
    opacity: 0
  });

$('button').one('click', function() {
  $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
  oT.animate({
    top: '-=50',
    opacity: 0
  }, function() {
    nT.animate({
      top: '-=50',
      opacity: 1
    });
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://www.quilabytes.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/light_shadow_blur_background_46792_1920x1200.jpg) no-repeat center;
  position: relative;
}

button {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  top: 65%;
}

#old,
#new {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
}

p {
  font-family: helvetica;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

  <div id="old">
    <p>Old Text</p>
  </div>
  <div id="new">
    <p>New Text</p>
  </div>
  <button>Click Me!</button>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't work when i insert it in html, do i have a mistake during the process?

Comment: My sure to follow all, HTML CSS & Javascript.

Comment: Your not loading jQuery correctly. Use this for the URL: `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js`

Comment: oh, yes i forgot . . Thanks Shivam, I appreciate you.
One more thing . . . Can i put a image instead of button?

Answer (score 0):

If DIV with text absolutely positioned, you should try `animate`:

```
$('#your_div_id').animate({'top':some_value, 'opacity':0},time);
```

if you need completely hide DIV, you need assign negative value to `some_value`.